# Turkish character problems while parsing (Android)

Tags: android, utf-8, html-parsing

I am parsing an html content and have output on my screen. This website have Turkish characters such as çÇşŞöÖğĞıİüÜ. I am not able to show them as proper characters, they are printed out as question marks yet.

Eclipse -> Project -> Properties -> Resource -> Text File Encoding = Inherited from container (Cp1254)

I searched web and found this solution:

Eclipse -> Project -> Properties -> Resource -> Text File Encoding = Other: UTF-8

However, it's not working. It only changes my files' current characters. (I have titles that have such characters on my activities)

Any help? Thanks in advance...

Comment: To clarify: You have only changed the encodning in your IDE, not in your app.

Comment: so, any suggestions to change it in my app :) is it related with my code really??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a real solution finally. Depending on where you are parsing from (I am retrieving data from a charset = iso-8859-9 and on Eclipse, using utf-8) you should make char replace operations. For my case,

```
    context = context.replaceAll("&#304;", "İ");
    context = context.replaceAll("&#305;", "ı");
    context = context.replaceAll("&#214;", "Ö");
    context = context.replaceAll("&#246;", "ö");
    context = context.replaceAll("&#220;", "Ü");
    context = context.replaceAll("&#252;", "ü");
    context = context.replaceAll("&#199;", "Ç");
    context = context.replaceAll("&#231;", "ç");
    context = context.replaceAll("&#286;", "Ğ");
    context = context.replaceAll("&#287;", "ğ");
    context = context.replaceAll("&#350;", "Ş");
    context = context.replaceAll("&#351;", "ş");
```

where context is a String that holds all of the parsed data and will be printed out on a TextView. That's all. I should have thought that a lot before!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you are parsing the html into memory. If you are retrieveing it from a file with the scanner class, and the html-file is saved as utf-8, then do like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8");
```

If you are reading it from the web with the `org.apache.http` package, and have the content as a `HttpEntity`-object, then do like this:

```
String content = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
```

I.e. it all depends on how you read the html-file. Usually you can specify the encoding when creating the reader. You will have to match this to the encoding the file is saved with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. html file is saved as iso-8859-9 and I use      java.net.HttpURLConnection . Answer didn't help me but I had changed the website content as I can use